# Use of "buenísimo" vs "mejorísimo"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, superlativos

If the absolute superlatives are superlatives, why can we use *buenísimo*? Shouldn't we use *mejorísimo*?

Comment: What do you mean? The use of *buenísimo* is consistent with other superlatives in Spanish (e.g.: from *blanco* you derive *blanquísimo*, not *más blanquísimo*).

Answer (score 2):

*Bueno* is just an adjective, it means "good". It does not compare things.
*Buenísimo* is not an absolute superlative but a normal one. It just means *muy bueno* → "very good". Many things can be *buenísimo* at the same time.

*Mejor* is a comparative. It is used to say that something is better, more *bueno* than something else: *Toyota es mejor que Honda* → "Toyota is better than Honda".

The particle *-ísimo* is a suffix that means "very": *dificil**ísimo*** → "very difficult", *rar**ísimo*** → "very rare". It is used to easily form superlatives from adjectives in Spanish.
It doesn't make sense to say ❌*mejor**ísimo***, just like it doesn't make sense to say "Toyota is very better than Honda".

Some adjectives like *bueno* use a different word like *mejor* when making comparisons, but in most cases you just use *más*: *Tú eres más guapo que yo* → "You are prettier than me"; *El Empire State es más alto que el edificio Chrysler* → "The Empire State building is taller than the Chrysler building"; *Otras preguntas podrían ser más interesantes que esta* → "Other questions might be more interesting than this one".

Finally, you have absolutes. In Spanish, you form those by preceding the comparative with a definite article (*el, la, lo* → the) — but, unlike in English, the form doesn't change. So: *Tú eres el más guapo* → "You are the prettiest"; *El edificio Burj Khalifa es el más alto* → "The Burj Khalifa building is the tallest"; *Esta pregunta es la más interesante* → "This question is the most interesting".

*Mejorísimo* would only be used in an exaggerated, almost wrong-on-purpose way, just like "very best"; and, just like it, it is grammatically incorrect (though "very best" is much more established and accepted in English, while most everybody would recognize *mejorísimo* as wrong in Spanish).

Note: **if** *mejorísimo* was right, I think it'd probably be spelled *mejorcísimo* instead, just like its diminutive *mejorcito*. Spanish ‍♂️.